# Powershell paths off (settings corrupt?)

Tags: powershell

I'm running Windows 10x64 with full updates on a Lenovo P70 laptop with 32GB of RAM.

My team is working on a complex powershell 5.1 solution.  We have a powershell window that opens a lot of other powershell windows which run some SQL.  Until a few days ago, everything worked fine.  Suddenly PowerShell 5.1 starting inserting "C:\windows\system32" in as the value for pwd.path where we find TXT files that will be read in.  We would literally get paths like "C:\windows\system32" when we were accessing the pwd.path variable.

Here is where its is being used:

```
$fr = [System.IO.Path]::Combine( ((pwd).Path), ($folderName) );
```

The entire PS1 script now fails spectacularly.  I looked at my powerhsell profiles, and they're all blank (just some comments at most).  I decided to try installing Powershell 6, and after two minor modifications, everything worked fine.  Thing is, my team has come up with a rather complex PS1 script solution, and we're about to put it into action.  Now is not the time to be switching from Powershell5 to Powershell6.  Also, I tried hard coding the path we need on Powershell5, and that worked.  Thing is, these scripts really need to be able to run from a relative folder that varies.  Everything runs fine on my colleague's identical computer.

From what I can tell, one of settings got corrupted.  Thing is, I don't know how to fix this.

Does anyone know what happened to my powerhsell?
Does anyone know how to fix it other than running Powershell6?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in my experience, the `$PWD` "present working directory" is ... oddly unreliable. you should grab the actual dir that you want to use ... and use that. something like `$PSScriptRoot` or even hard coding a location.

Comment: From your question it's unclear if the pathes are relative to the script location or to the current directoy (powershell and .net aren't always congruent in that) Why don't you use `Join-Path`? Are you running powershell elevated?

Comment: Does your code try to start processes as admin like `start-process powershell -verb runas`? That always opens up in `C:\Windows\System32` for me.

Comment: @AdminOfThings that is the route we take, and it only recently broke.

Comment: @LotPings we're using relative paths.  Powershell is elevated.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: The question is still: relative to what, current location (which defaults `C:\Windows\System32` with runas) or script location.

Comment: @LotPings relative to current location.  We move away from C:\Windows\System32, but PS still thinks its there.

Comment: Do you use a .Net or a PowerShell command to change the current dir? `Set-Location` / `Push-Location`.

Comment: @LotPings powershell

Comment: @DanGifford - as LotPings pointed out, using `-RunAs` will set the $PWD to system32. [*grin*] never, ever, _ever_ presume that where PoSh thinks is your current location matches where dotnet thinks your current location is ... or even were explorer thinks you are. avoid relative paths whenever possible & start out from a known location whenever you can. the `$PSScriptRoot` is usually a good starting point - another is `$env:temp`.